# HttpUrlConnection "PUT" Request also sends "GET" Request

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

My issue is that when I use `HttpURLConnection` to send a `PUT` request to my `REST API`, it sends a `GET` request first, then a `PUT` request. I was wondering if any of my code I have to send a `PUT` request is causing it to also send a `GET` request.

I know that this issue occurs in my `Android` code because I also use `Postman` to send `PUT` requests, and I never have an issue.

Below is a copy of the function I use to send `HttpUrlConnection` requests.

```
public String HTTPConnection(String requestType, String url, String input, Context context, Activity activity){
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL OBJ = new URL(url);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) OBJ.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod(requestType);
            switch (requestType.toLowerCase()) {
                case "get":
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                    String inputLine;
                    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                    int i = 1;
                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(inputLine);
                        i++;
                    }
                    in.close();
                    return response.toString();
                case "put":
                    if (!input.equals("")){
                        OBJ.openStream();
                        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
                        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                        connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    }
                    Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                    writer.write(input);
                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close();
                    connection.getInputStream();
                    return "";
                default:
                    return "";
            }
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OBJ.openStream();` sends a GET request (see [java.net.URL.openStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream())), since it opens an input stream for reading the contents of that URL.

Comment: I just tested it, and the problems have disappeared. Thank you for your input! This has been something that has been bothering me for a while now. I haven't been able to figure out what was happening since I just used sample code from other projects.